# Fragment not loading

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, simpleadapter, pagerslidingtabstrip

I'm trying to inflate a fragment with listview in one of the two tabs in my application.

But, what am getting is all this: (this goes on and on forever.. )

[image]

This is what I'm trying to do.

**ListFragment.Java**

```
public class ListFragment extends Fragment {

  Other methods 
   ...
  //some code

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment


        java.util.List<HashMap<String, String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

        for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
            HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
            hm.put("tit", "Title : " + title[i]);
            hm.put("init","Initial Price : " + cur_price[i]);
            hm.put("cur","Current Price  : " + init_price[i]);
            hm.put("img", d[i].toString());
            aList.add(hm);
        }



        // Keys used in Hashmap
        String[] from = { "tit","init","cur","img"};

        // Ids of views in listview_layout
        int[] to = { R.id.tit,R.id.init,R.id.cur,R.id.img};

        // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
        // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(context, aList, R.layout.listview_layout, from, to);

        // Getting a reference to listview of fragment_list_items.xml layout file
        ListView listView = ( ListView ) view.findViewById(R.id.listview);

        // Setting the adapter to the listView
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_items, container, false);

    }
```

Where is the problem please?

**EDIT :** The same code worked well when I had no tabs but only a single activity to display.

**My layout files :**

**fragment_list_items.xml :**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context="com.example.nikhil.amazon1.ListFragment">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</FrameLayout>
```

**ListView.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription=""
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/init"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cur"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you must create view by inflater, coz u cant findItemById from it.
And rename your class. ListFragment -> otherName.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_items, container, false)

    java.util.List<HashMap<String, String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

    for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
        hm.put("tit", "Title : " + title[i]);
        hm.put("init","Initial Price : " + cur_price[i]);
        hm.put("cur","Current Price  : " + init_price[i]);
        hm.put("img", d[i].toString());
        aList.add(hm);
    }



    // Keys used in Hashmap
    String[] from = { "tit","init","cur","img"};

    // Ids of views in listview_layout
    int[] to = { R.id.tit,R.id.init,R.id.cur,R.id.img};

    // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
    // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(context, aList, R.layout.listview_layout, from, to);

    // Getting a reference to listview of main.xml layout file
    ListView listView = ( ListView ) view.findViewById(R.id.listview);

    // Setting the adapter to the listView
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return view;

}
```

Comment: Do you have only list view in your fragment ?

Comment: Yes, I only have listview. I'll update the question with my XML layout files. Any help pl? :)

Comment: Seems it's very fun mistake ) You named your class ListFragment, it already defined in android SDK. So when you set your fragment in tabView(example), like // return new ListFragment(); - You just make clear object from DEFINED ListFragment. Try to rename you class; Post result

Comment: Add visible item like text view into your R.layout.listview_layout xml to check my version.

Comment: Thanks @Max Vitruk . It worked. I changed the class name. Moreover, I had a problem with context, which I fixed. Thanks for your time. :)

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem. You might need a fragment element instead of a frame layout.
You can try with <fragment ... /> in fragment_list_items.xml